# Currvita: fill space in left column

Tags: cv, currvita

I'm searching for a solution to span dates in the left column of cvlist elements over the available vertical space. This is my current result:

[image: Current]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[]{currvita}
\begin{document}
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1pt}

    \begin{cv}{John Doe}
        \begin{cvlist}{Professional Experience}
            \item[\smash{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 08/2016\\$\vert$ \\07/2019}}]Position\begin{itemize}
                \item Item 1
                \item Item 2
                \item Item 3
                \item Item 4
            \end{itemize}
        \end{cvlist}
    \end{cv}
\end{document}
```

And this is what I would like to realize:

[image: Expected]

Thanks for your help!

Sebastian